# How can I get specific values using a key from json using AngularJS foreach

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I have JSON  object  returned from elastic search like below
[image]

How can i get the **Agent** and **calls** value from this JSON.

```
$scope.results = client
                .query(oQuery.query($scope.queryTerm || '*'))
                .doSearch().then(function (body) {
             $scope.results = body.hits.hits;
             var resultstofilter = $scope.results;
             var log = [];
              angular.forEach(results, function(result, key) {
                angular.forEach(result, function(value, key) {
                   this.push(key + ': ' + value);
                 }, log);
              }, log);
             console.log(resultstofilter);
            }, function (error) {
              console.trace(error.message);
              });;
```

The above prints the same objects again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere you need to filters the keys if you only want the "Agents" and "Calls" ones.

```
$scope.results = client
            .query(oQuery.query($scope.queryTerm || '*'))
            .doSearch().then(function (body) {
         $scope.results = body.hits.hits;
         var resultstofilter = [];

         for (var i=0; i<$scope.results.length; ++i) {
           var result = $scope.results[i];
           resultstofilter[i] = {};
           for (var key in result) {
             // If all you want are keys that doesn't start with '_'
             // you can also test key.substring(0, 1) !== '_'
             if (key === 'Agent' || key === 'Calls') {
               resultstofilter[i][key] = result[key];
             }
           }
         }

         console.log(resultstofilter);
        }, function (error) {
          console.trace(error.message);
        });;
```

Comment: Thanks, but am getting the key as 0,1,2,3,4

Comment: Sorry, it should be better now (no need for Object.keys)

Comment: ya now its better, but still does not go inside the object .they keys are actually id,_index,scope etc